# Who to get id into html output of form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have this:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do %>
```

That generates this html-Output:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/session" method="post">
```

I need to set a id for the form. How can I add a id?

Answer (score 2):

an html id?

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, :html => {:id => "foobar"}) do %>
```

or an id to be returned with the form data? Then either add it to the url or add a hidden field

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, :html => { :class => "form_class", :id => "new_post" }) do |f| %>
```